# Problema com a Bean Springboot

Tags: spring-boot

Bom dia, pessoal estou fazendo uma API com spring boot mas minha bean não está sendo localizada, alguém poderia me ajudar, da outra vez não encontrei esse problema.
Segue Códigos:

```
 @RestController
    @RequestMapping("/api")
    public class PessoaController {

        private PessoaImpl pesimpl;


        @Autowired
        public PessoaController(PessoaImpl pesimpl) {
            super();
            this.pesimpl = pesimpl;
        }

        @GetMapping(value="/buscar", produces="application/json")
        public String trazerTodos() {
            return "Tudo aqui de novo!";
        }

        @PostMapping("/enviarDados")
        public void inserirDados(@RequestBody String data) {

        }

    }

@Service
public class PessoaImpl implements PessoaService {

    private PessoaRepo pessoaRepository;

    @Autowired
    public PessoaImpl(PessoaRepo pessoaRepository) {
        super();
        this.pessoaRepository = pessoaRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Pessoa> buscarTodos() {
        return this.pessoaRepository.findAll();
    }

}


@Document(collection = "pessoa")
public class Pessoa {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private String id;

    private String nome;
    private int contato;


    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }
    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }
    public int getContato() {
        return contato;
    }
    public void setContato(int contato) {
        this.contato = contato;
    }



}


public interface PessoaRepo extends MongoRepository<Pessoa, String>{

    List<Pessoa> findAll();

}


public interface PessoaService {

    public List<Pessoa> buscarTodos();

}


@ComponentScan({"com.example.controllers"})
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@SpringBootApplication
public class TestandoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TestandoApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Seria algo relacionado a annotation? Se puderem me ajudar

Comment: Oque você quer dizer com "minha bean não está sendo localizada", quem não localizou? Que erro voc^esta recebendo? em qual momento? você pode mudar a sua pergunta?

Answer (score 0):

Creio que o correto seria utilizar a interface e não a classe que a implementa:

```
    @RestController
    @RequestMapping("/api")
    public class PessoaController {

        @Autowired
        private PessoaService pesservice;

        @GetMapping(value="/buscar", produces="application/json")
        public String trazerTodos() {
            return "Tudo aqui de novo!";
        }

        @PostMapping("/enviarDados")
        public void inserirDados(@RequestBody String data) {

        }

    }
```

Dessa forma também não é necessário utilizar um construtor